# Underlying flow to explain crash in allocated memory

Tags: c

I would like to understand what is happening, when calling "free()", that makes the program crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fd = fopen("junk.txt", "r");
    int buffer_size = 42; //random number just for this example
    if (fd != NULL)
    {
        char* data = calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(uint8_t));
        if (data != NULL)
        {
            uint32_t read_size = fread(data, 1, buffer_size, fd);
            if (read_size == buffer_size)
            {
                char* some_data = strstr(data, "DATA:");
                if (some_data != NULL)
                {
                    uint32_t some_data_size = some_data - data;
                    char* stuff = calloc(some_data_size + 1, sizeof(uint8_t));
                    if (stuff != NULL)
                    {
                        some_data[some_data_size] = '\0'; // removing this line prevents a crash
                        //... doing stuff with the data
                        memcpy(stuff, some_data + 6, some_data_size);
                        free(stuff);
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose(fd);
            free(data);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know the line that causes the crash:

> some_data[some_data_size] = '\0';

I know that I'm writing to "null-terminate" allocated memory. But Why is this not ok?

I though that when performing a "free()", The underlying "magic" would deallocate the memory starting at the "first" address up to a certain size.

**So, if someone could explain what I don't understand, it would be very nice.**

Comment: There's no guarantee that the data you read from the file will be a null-terminated string. Therefore the call to `strstr(data, ...)` leads to *undefined behavior*. On some systems there

Comment: Also, why are you treating what seems like a text-file as a binary file?

Comment: free(fd) is a typo

Comment: Why does `42` show up here? It's a *magic number* that really shouldn't be hard-coded like that.

Comment: the 42 is just a value to help me simplify the code.

Comment: And if you know the maximum size of the buffer, why use dynamic allocation? Just use `char data[BUFSIZE];` as long as BUFSIZE isn't too large.

Comment: same reason. present code as simple as possible, yet close to my use case.

Comment: "Just a value" is what I'm talking about here. Create variables to encapsulate this, like `int buffer_size = 42` or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, my first comment got locked when trying to fix a mistake edit... Anyway, what I was trying to say is that on some systems there might be a [`memmem`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html) function that works similarly to `strstr` but for generic memory. But it's availability is limited.

Comment: Anyway, if you're getting a crash from `free()`, you probably have a buffer overflow somewhere that causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Use a memory debugging tool like `valgrind` to track this down.

Comment: Well, I changed the code to avoid the error. But, not understanding why this happens bothers me (I want to understand). Looking at the debugger, the memory addresses "seem" ok. Thus the question. Is my comprehension of how free() works is wrong?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, thanks for the relevant comments

Answer (score 3):

The call to `free` isn't the problem.  You have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code prior to that where you're writing past the end of allocated memory, and the call to `free` is just when the crash manifests.

Assuming that the string "DATA" is at the start of the file, this line:

```
uint32_t some_data_size = (data + 42) - some_data;
```

Will set `some_data_size` to 42.  That means that this line:

```
some_data[some_data_size] = '\0';
```

Will write one element past the end of the memory segment that was allocated.

This is also a problem:

```
memcpy(stuff, some_data + 6, some_data_size);
```

Since `some_data_size` is based on starting to count from `some_data` instead of `some_data + 6`, so this will read 6 positions past the end of allocated memory.

You need to allocate one extra byte to store the terminating null character you want to add:

```
char* data = calloc(42 + 1, sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Set the data size so it doesn't include the "DATA:" string:

```
uint32_t some_data_size = (data + 42) - (some_data - 6);
```

And set the null terminator at the proper place:

```
some_data[some_data_size + 6] = '\0'
```

Comment: I agree with you regarding the "index" I'm using. Some of the values that I entered do not make sense. I modified the code snippet to remove them. The modified snippet still produces the error. I upvoted your answer, and writing this comment to avoid confusion for later readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `some_data_size` is too big, causing `some_data[some_data_size] = '\0';` to access outside of the allocation of data.

Explanation:

```
*data      = 1. value
*(data+1)  = 2. value
*(data+2)  = 3. value
...
*(data+42) = 43. value
```

So your calculation of `some_data_size` is one to big if you add 42.
It should be

`uint32_t some_data_size = (data + 41) - some_data;`

Can you try that out ?